# Is Privacy's Delete History button supposed to delete Nautilus' Recent Items?

Tags: nautilus

I've opened two files and deleted the last hour history, in Recent Items' tab, in Privacy options (Ubuntu 13.04).

However, Nautilus keeps showing the two files in Recent files.

I've found the `.local/share/recently-used.xbel` file, from where I can manually remove the files reference, but I think deleting the last hour history should have done it automatically, shouldn't it?

Comment: Here, a user who has a global view of Ubuntu asking "Why Recent Items are not being deleted even using the Privacy app in Unity?" http://askubuntu.com/questions/304274/why-recent-items-are-not-being-deleted-even-using-the-privacy-app-in-unity

Answer (score 1):

No!
Privacy's Delete History button is **not** supposed to delete Nautilus' Recent Items.

Privacy's Delete History button is supposed to delete Recent Items in `Files & Folders` lens of Unity Dash.

Comment: But Privacy is a system wide config (All settings)... It should be clear in Privacy it is restricted to Unity lens.

Comment: @YuriC - Nautilus is totally different product which is maintained by GNOME team and not Ubuntu team. That's why changing the privacy settings of Ubuntu doesn't have any effect on privacy settings of Nautilus.  
If you are still eager to delete your recent items in Nautilus then get GNOME 3.8. Nautilus 3.8 is shipped with GNOME 3.8 which has this feature according to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-privacy/+bug/1122179) bug report.
**Beware** GNOME 3 may break your Ubuntu system.

Comment: I disagree. Nautilus is utterly part of Ubuntu for years and integration between OS and its applications is one of the great efforts of Ubuntu development.