# Why Recent Items are not being deleted even using the Privacy app in Unity?

Tags: unity, 13.04, nautilus

I wanted to remove certain things from the Recent folder and used the Privacy app as indicated on this site. However, nothing has changed. The files are still in the folder and , even though I changed the settings to not track certain files, it still does.

Help?

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 if that helps.

Comment: I think the Privacy App is only for Dash and applications that support Zeitgeist.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the `/home/username/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` file, from where I can manually remove the files reference.

I think the Privacy settings should delete it too, but a person said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296970/is-privacys-delete-history-button-supposed-to-delete-nautilus-recent-items/301627) that Privacy's Delete History button is supposed to delete Recent Items in Files & Folders lens of Unity Dash only. I disagree. I think it should. But it doesn't.